# product of lists, not necessarily all the lists at the same time

Tags: python

I have three lists (L1, L2, L3), something like :

```
L1 = [1,2]
L2 = ['a','b']
L3 = ['A','B']
```

I want to compute the product of L1*L2*L3, id est,

```
itertools.product(L1,L2,L3) = [ [1,'a','A'], [1,'a','B'], ... ]
```

but I want to take or not in account some lists; hence,[1,], [ 1, 'a' ] would be a part of the result, like ['a',], ['a', 'B'] and so on.

Any idea to help me ? Thanks !

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I want to take or not in account some lists"? What should the result be for the lists you gave?

Comment: I'd like to have [1, 'a'] as a part of the result (=here, L3 ignored) or [2, 'B'] (=here, L2 ignored), and so on, plus the usual result using the three  lists [1, 'a', 'A'], [1, 'a', 'B], ...

Comment: So you want all the lists containing zero or one items from each of the given lists?

Comment: all the list containing zero, one, two and three items for each of the given lists, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `powerset` function given in the [itertools examples](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes). `powerset([L1,L2,L3])` will give you all subsets of the set of 3 lists. For each subset you can take the cartesian product, and then chain them all together.

```
>>> from itertools import chain, product
>>> result = chain.from_iterable(product(*lists) for lists in powerset([L1,L2,L3]))        
>>> list(result)

[(), (1,), (2,), ('a',), ('b',), ('A',), ('B',), (1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'a'), 
(2, 'b'), (1, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (2, 'A'), (2, 'B'), ('a', 'A'), ('a', 'B'), 
('b', 'A'), ('b', 'B'), (1, 'a', 'A'), (1, 'a', 'B'), (1, 'b', 'A'), 
(1, 'b', 'B'), (2, 'a', 'A'), (2, 'a', 'B'), (2, 'b', 'A'), (2, 'b', 'B')]
```